# Windows 10 Bing Metro UI apps no longer open (e.g. News, Weather, Sport)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, modern-ui

I recently did an upgrade to the latest Windows 10 insider preview (to test out the Ubuntu Bash on Windows).

After testing I rolled back to a previous stable version (then disabled the insider preview updates), so I'm now back on a stable version.

But now none of the Bing Modern-UI apps open.

If I click News, Weather or Sport the mouse pointer spins for a few seconds and then nothing. If I have Task Manager open, the apps don't even show up.

If I go to the Windows Store page for the apps to try and uninstall them, I don't get any options as the page loads but the spinner on the app page just spins forever (so the uninstall/install button never shows up).

I've attempted to reinstall the default apps from Powershell using `Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"` but it hasn't fixed anything.

Other Modern-UI apps work (Like Mail, Calendar etc).

I've also created a new user account on the machine and the Bing apps work fine under that user account (they just don't work on my user account).

Does anyone have any ideas of what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug within Windows 10. Microsoft have issued an update to fix it:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3152599